# Need help getting Zapier scripting example working in JSFiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, json, underscore.js

Zapier has a scripting language but no way to really test in real-time. So I want to use their example for my own connection/data.

I have an application that uses XML for their API output, Zapier requires JSON to function. So it requires me to convert from XML to JSON using the link below.

Here is the link to Zapier's scripting example to convert XML to JSON:

[Zapier - MadMimi XML to JSON](https://zapier.com/developer/documentation/handling-xml/#input)

How can I get that working in JSFiddle? The reason I want to get it into JSFiddle is so I can manipulate my XML output.

My XML output looks like this:

[XML Output on PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/r4xPjieY)

Comment: Please include the XLM into your question.

Comment: @SableFoste I couldn't figure out how to format it properly. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Brian here, one of the developers at Zapier.

I've put together this JSFiddle example for you: http://jsfiddle.net/5t2pfpk4/

```
Zap = {
    audience_list_post_poll: function(bundle) {
        // use the provided dom methods with a familiar jquery interface
        xmlElements = $($.parseXML(bundle.response.content)).find('list');
        // return a list of objects that are json serializable 
        return _.map(xmlElements, function(listElement) {
            listElement = $(listElement);
            // pull off each attribute manually, place into object
            return {
                id:                 listElement.attr('id'),
                subscriber_count:   listElement.attr('subscriber_count'),
                display_name:       listElement.attr('display_name'),
                name:               listElement.attr('name'),
            };
        });
    },
};

// Copy me from the bundle log
var bundle = {
    response: {
        content: '<YOUR_XML_HERE><list></list></YOUR_XML_HERE>'
    }
};

results = Zap.audience_list_post_poll(bundle);
console.log(results);
```

Steps:

1. Create a new example and set JQuery lib to 1.9
2. Add an external source for Underscore, http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js
3. Slap the code above into the JS section
4. Copy and paste a real bundle from our Bundle Log (or you can just put in the XML you want)
5. Tweak to your hearts content

When you are done you can put that back in your app.

P.S. We know the real-time editing is a bit painful right now and have some ideas to improve it in future releases.